# How to launch psci without compiling current project?

Tags: purescript

My project currently has a compiler error, but that should not deter me from opening an interactive PureScript session, yet it does:

```
$ pulp psci
Error found:
at /Users/srid/code/PS/Pallanguzhi/src/Board.purs line 41, column 50 - line 41, column 50

  Unable to parse module:
  [..]

See https://github.com/purescript/purescript/wiki/Error-Code-ErrorParsingModule for more information,
or to contribute content related to this error.
```

How do I launch a psci shell regardless of the state of the project? I don't care about not being able to import project modules; just need a bare shell.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to do this now, other than running PSCi directly and providing a glob of some subset of the modules which are known to build.

We have an open issue to track this already.